# Strange lines in /var/log/message folder of Centos machine

Tags: linux, centos, syslog, rsyslog

Below are lines from my `/var/log/messages`.  Can someone help me to understand what these lines mean?  I am running a syslog server on this machine.  I want to know if these messages would stop the syslog server from reading events on other machines ?  How does one prevent or remove these type of messages ?

```
May 17 03:36:40 **** rsyslogd-***: action 'action 14' suspended, next retry is Tue May 17 03:37:10 2016 [v8.18.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
May 17 03:36:40 **** rsyslogd-***: action 'action 15' suspended, next retry is Tue May 17 03:37:10 2016 [v8.18.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
May 17 03:36:40 **** rsyslogd-***: action 'action 16' suspended, next retry is Tue May 17 03:37:10 2016
```

Comment: Did you follow and read the information on the linked page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [a bug in rsyslog](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/35).

[The webpage mentioned in your logs](http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007) says this (slightly edited by me):

"This not a real error status per se. It tells that an output module suspended itself, which can happen whenever there is a problem talking to the output destination (e.g. a remote server may be down). However, this is an internal state that should not be exposed to the users. So if you see this message, please let the developers know (inside [this forum thread](http://kb.monitorware.com/kbeventdb-detail-id-6925.html)) where and when it occurs."